How can I test if the power jack is working on my ThinkPad X230?
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X230, and I'm experiencing issues with the device. It kind of mysteriously shut off one day and I have been unable to turn it back on/charge it. I suspect the power jack might not be functioning properly. I have a multimeter from iFixit that I would like to use.
How can I test if the power jack is working on my ThinkPad X230?

It is also possible the battery itself is dead.

@LPChip wouldn't the device still power on while connected with AC/DC plug?

Highly depends on the device. If the battery is removable, you often can still use it with a dead battery (you may have to remove the battery though), but if the battery is internally connected, often the wiring is such that if the battery fails, no matter if the power supply is okay, the laptop won't turn on.

It looks that the X230 has a round tip power supply - so you should  be able to measure it with the voltmeter.
Taking precautions to make sure you only measure the output at the tip (ie DC end, not the wall end) -

Set the multimeter to measure DC voltage - If your multimeter is the one at https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/How+To+Use+A+Multimeter/25632#s65002 that is the symbol with the Wave, a straight line and then a dotted line on top of a V symbol.  If its an older multimeter select the "200" setting on the top left in the quadrant marked with a V

Plug the black lead  into the COM / Common / Ground connector on the multimeter.

Plug the red lead into the RIGHT hand lead - ie the one marked with the battery symbol + V + ohm symble and a few others.   IT IS IMPORTANT YOU DONT PLUG IT INTO THE TERMINAL MARKED A.

With the power supply powered on, attach one end of the lead to the outside metal ring at the end of the power supply, and touch the other end to the tip in the center.   Its better to use the black lead to the outside, but not important.   The multimeter should provide a reading of the number of volts.  If there is a negative on the reading thats OK, just ignore the negative, it means the leads are round the opposite way to the way.


This will tell you the output of the supply.  If it is less then 19 volts it is probably not working correctly.
Note that this is a simple/crude measurement.  It is not measuring current which would require you to cut the cable and use the Amps setting on the voltmeter.  It is possible  that the power supply is able to output > 19 volts when it is not connected to the laptop but is not able to do so once the laptop is pulling power.  If it reads a low value (or 0) then you can conclude the power supply is not working, but short of testing the power supply in another laptop or doing more advanced tests which require cutting into the cable or creating a custom dongle which effectively does the same thing - so you can put the multimeter in series with the supply - you can't fully test this.
